# How to bypass git "Tell me who you are" for a shared repository

Tags: git, gitlab, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, cicd

Let's say, there is a repository named **repoA**. In the **gitlab-ci.yml** of this repository, I would like to clone (and modify) another repository named **repoB**.

repoA and repoB belong to the same Gitlab group, and all the members of this group have maintainer role for both of these repositories. I created an access token for **repoB** to use for authentication while cloning the repository (inside the yml of **repoA**), but despite the token, git still requires to declare user.name and user.mail to commit to **repoB**.

The script in gitlab-ci.yml is triggered after each commit to repoA, so how can I make that repoA does not require configuration to access repoB (using the access token)?

This is basically how my gitlab-ci.yml looks like:

```
build-job:      
  image: "node:16.13.0"
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm ci
    - npm run docs:build
    - cd ..
    - git clone https://<token_name>:<token>@<url_to_repoB>
```

Comment: You would `git submodule add` the other repo. `but despite the token,` How do you clone it? Please post the code.

Comment: @KamilCuk I have just edited my post.

Comment: `user.name` and `user.email` is not used for authentication when cloning, it's just when committing. Are you sure this error is given when you try to clone? I ask because you can easily clone a repository without having those two configuration items set.

Comment: You are totally right @LasseV.Karlsen. It throws the error while committing to repoB, not while cloning.

Comment: And in that case git is correct. You can either configure these configuration items separately, or pass them on the commit command line with `git -c user.email=email@domain.fr -c user.name='Your Name' commit ...` (I believe that is the correct order and syntax). Either way, to *commit*, git needs to know who is committing.

Comment: Yes, adding an anonymous credential solved the problem. I thought I could manage this without adding anything, but it turned out this is not the case. Thanks Lasse!